# How can I determine exactly how much downtime needed during the scheduled maintenance window in Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

How can I determine exactly how much downtime is needed during the scheduled maintenance window in Autonomous Database? Also, how can I find out about what's included in a given patch?

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation as "Principal Product Manager at Oracle" in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/maintenance-windows-patching.html#GUID-94150883-EE29-4EED-94A7-44ECCEC05B99), your database remains available during the maintenance window. Your existing database connections may get disconnected briefly; however, you can immediately reconnect and continue using your database. If your application uses Oracle Transparent Application Continuity (TAC), you avoid these brief disconnects altogether.

In order to see what bug fixes are delivered in these maintenance windows, you can run the following query:

```
-- To view patch information for all available patches
SELECT * FROM DBA_CLOUD_PATCH_INFO;

-- For patch ADBS-21.7.1.1
SELECT * FROM DBA_CLOUD_PATCH_INFO WHERE PATCH_VERSION = 'ADBS-21.7.1.1';
```

Disclaimer: I’m a Product Manager at Oracle.

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation as "Principal Product Manager at Oracle" in your answer.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for the heads up. Done!